# Is ValidationRule able to prevent Control status from being updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, validationrule

Maybe I am not using `ValidationRule` correctly, if so, please show me the correct way.

Currently, I have implemented a class `WarningForUncheckRule` inherited from `ValidationRule`, and bind it to a binding.

```xml
<cc:StarCheckBox>
    <cc:StarCheckBox.IsChecked>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Path>IsFavorate</Binding.Path>
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <vm:WarningForUncheckRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
            <Binding.Mode>TwoWay</Binding.Mode>
        </Binding>
    </cc:StarCheckBox.IsChecked>
</cc:StarCheckBox>
```

I implement the code and return `false` as result (for test purpose here):

```
public class WarningForUncheckRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, 
                                              CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, null);
    }
}
```

My question is if I return `false` here, there is only the error UI showing with error message, but the UI status **is still changed**.

Is it possible to use `false` ValidateResult to **prevent the UI from being update**?

If no, is there other way in binding to accomplish this?

Comment: What you mean by the UI status is still changed?

Comment: I mean I suppose the false return value will prevent the UI status from being changed, but in fact, the UI is still changed even validation failed.

Comment: In the set just reject the change.

Comment: What do you mean by "reject"? How?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke property changed on the viewmodel after the validation and it shall return the old value to UI which was before the edit.